# Did any official comic Spider-Men not appear in Spider-Verse?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-verse

The original *Spider-Verse* event was touted as featuring "every Spider-Man **ever**."

[image]

Due to the [sheer number of *Spider-Man* adaptations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_other_media), this isn't actually true.

Is it true that every official (as in Marvel created or licensed) comic version of Spider-Man appeared in the event? To avoid the list being too broad, I'll exclude variations on characters like Kaine and Ben Reilly, as well as Spider-Men who are functionally identical in character design and personality to the original 616 Spider-Man.

Comment: Given the number of Spider-Man stories seen in the two runs of *What If?* (not to mention the event-oriented and "one-shot" runs in more recent times), it's unlikely. In many of those stires, there's no difference to Spider-Man's costume, or minimal differences. For instance: from the very firdt *What If*, there's the Spider-Man who became a member of the Fantastic Four at the start of his career - his costume would have a 4 or a 5 in the middle of the spider on his chest. Few of the "What If" variations even have that much to distinguish them.

Comment: @RDFozz [Actually...](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/images/1300-4328684) However, I have edited the question to reflect that concern.

Comment: Discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Spiderman/comments/2xe6p0/wheres_that_spider_a_postspiderverse_analysis_of/) in considerable detail. In short, lots.

Comment: @Valorum Definitely some useful information, but it doesn't seem conclusive.

Comment: OK, I was expecting that some insane geek poet adapted all of the stories in iambic pentameter.

Comment: Not sure about Spider-Verse but the new Spider-Geddon crossover promises EVERY Spider-Man ever. So far, Supaidaman, the PS4 Spider-Man, and even the Tsum-Tsum Spider-Man are appearing.

Comment: @Gothamite24 Does the spider-man from the 90s animated series appear in it?

Comment: @Wade-In Spider-Verse or Spider-Geddon?

Comment: Does the 1610 version ever meet anyone else other than Miles? He was never included, was he?